# Using $\epsilon-\delta$ definition to show $\frac{\sqrt{9-x}-3}{x}$ as $x\to 0$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, epsilon-delta

Given this $\frac{\sqrt{9-x}-3}{x}-\frac{1}{6}$ I managed to reduce it to $\frac{1}{6}$ so I'm not sure if I made an error there. What I am trying to show is that there is a limit at $0$ so we have
$0<|x|<\delta$ implies $\left|\frac{\sqrt{9-x}-3}{x}-\frac{1}{6}\right|<\epsilon$. I'm struggling with this a bit and I've had some trouble finding helpful references so some more thorough responses are greatly appreciated!

Comment: Correct. That is why we take $|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$ so $L=\frac{1}{6} \Rightarrow -L=-\frac{1}{6}$

Comment: You want to show that you can make $\frac{\sqrt{9-x}-3}{x}-\left(-\frac{1}{6}\right)$ small in absolute value by taking $x$ suitably close to $0$.

Comment: And $- \,-1/6$ is ... ?

Comment: I see the minus sign I missed. My bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT:

$$\left|\frac{\sqrt{9-x}-3}{x}+\frac{1}{6}\right|=\left|\frac16-\frac{1}{\sqrt{9-x}+3}\right|=\frac{\frac16 |x|}{(\sqrt{9-x}+3)^2}$$

Comment: @az89 Please let me know how I can improve my answer.  I really want to give you the best answer I can.

Answer (score 1):

Just to make sure I'm clear here and that everything is answered thoroughly we consider

$\frac{1}{(\sqrt{9-x}+3)^2}$ we can restrict $\delta<5$ which gives

$\frac{1}{(\sqrt{9-x}+3)^2}<\frac{1}{(\sqrt{4}+3)^2}<\frac{1}{25}$

Giving

$\left| \frac{x}{150} \right|< \epsilon$

So we take $0<|x|<\min\left(5,150\epsilon\right)$

Comment: That looks fine!  Well done.

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.

Comment: There's a small problem. I think you mean $$\frac1{(\sqrt{4}+3)^2},$$ rather than $$\frac1{\sqrt{4}+3}.$$

Comment: Also, I have no idea what "$\left\lvert\frac\delta{150}\right\rvert\epsilon$" means.

Comment: Just some formatting issues that arose.